# Python Paramiko: Error 13 acces denied

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

The following is a Python Paramiko script trying to make a server.
Whenever I run the script I get the error saying access denied.
The details of the error is posted down below.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
import paramiko


from os.path import expanduser
keypath = expanduser("~/Desktop/test_rsa.key")
host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename=keypath)

class Server (paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED

    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if (username == 'use') and (password == 'pass'):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

try:
    host=""
    global sock
    sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host,22))
    sock.listen(1)
    print "[+] Listening for connection"
```

except Exception, e:
       print  "[] Listen/Bing Failed:" + str(e)

```
try:
    client,addr=socket.accept()
    print" [+] got connection from" + str(addr)
    t=paramiko.Transport(client)
    t.load_server_moduli()
    t.add_server_key(host_key)
    server=Server()
   t.start_server(server=server)
   global chan
   print chan
   print chan.recv(1024)
   chan.send("Oh yes I can see that")

except:
    print "[-] Conncetion Terminated"
    pass
```

Hello, I m trying to run a server script with help of paramiko.
Whenever I run the the script I get The following error:

```
[] Listen/Bing Failed:[Errno 13] Permission denied
[-] Conncetion Terminated
```

Please help me regarding it.

Yours Sincerely,

Vidit Shah

Comment: Means what it says -- your operating system said you weren't allowed to do something. If you printed the full stack trace, not just the `str`ingification, then we'd be able to tell exactly which call failed -- but either way, it's probably going to mean looking into firewall rules, or file permissions, or otherwise something operating-system-enforced.

Comment: ...but anyhow, the very first place to start here is by printing a stack trace, and including it in your question. And BTW, if you can generate the same bug by just doing a socket connection without paramiko, then you should remove paramiko from your question -- building the smallest and simplest reproducer that generates the same problem is part of the **M**inimal criteria specified for a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ERROR:root:Something awful happened!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vidit/PycharmProjects/untitled6/server.py", line 41, in <module>
    client,addr=socket.accept()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'accept'
 Traceback error

Comment: That means you're dealing with the socket *module*, not a socket *object*. `accept()` can be called on the latter.

Comment: See if you get the same error from *this*: `import socket; s = socket.socket(); s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 22)); s.accept()`

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, UNIX operating systems do not allow non-root users to bind to ports below 1024. Services which bind to these ports thus typically do so as root during their startup, and then switch to a less-privileged user only after opening the socket.

Use a port in a higher range, not port 22.